# Return Text from a SwiftUI View

Tags: swiftui

I have a custom `View` that's basically wrapping `Text` with some additional functionality. E.g. formatting the text differently based on a value in the environment.

I want to use this custom view in place of a `Text`, i.e. I want to be able to use modifiers like `.bold()` on it.
Is it possible to return a `Text` from a `View` struct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is 2 ways for you:

### Way 1: You can use `.bold()`  just on your CustomView!

```
struct CustomTextView: View {
    
    @Environment(\.font) var environmentFont: Font?
    
    private let boldAllowed: Bool
    let string: String
    
    
    private init(boldAllowed: Bool, string: String) {
        self.boldAllowed = boldAllowed
        self.string = string
        
    }
    
    init(_ string: String) {
        self.init(boldAllowed: false, string: string)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        
        Text(string)
            .font(boldAllowed ? environmentFont?.bold() : environmentFont)
            .foregroundColor(Color.red)                                      //  <--- :::  some custom work here!  :::
        
    }
    
    func bold() -> CustomTextView {
        
        return CustomTextView(boldAllowed: true, string: string)
        
    }
    
}
```

### use case:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            
            Text("Hello, World!")
            
            CustomTextView("Hello, World!")
                .bold()
            
            CustomTextView("Hello, World!")
            
        }
        .font(Font.title.italic())
        
    }
    
}
```

### Result:

[image]

---

### Way 2: You can use `.bold()` on any View you want!

***I think this is the best possible way, because it is less code and usable on any view!***

```
struct CustomBoldTextViewModifier: ViewModifier {
    
    @Environment(\.font) var environmentFont: Font?

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {

        return content
            .environment(\.font, environmentFont?.bold())
        
    }
    
}

extension View {

    func bold() -> some View {

        return self.modifier(CustomBoldTextViewModifier())
        
    }
    
}
```

### use case:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            
            Text("Hello, World!")
  
        }
        .bold()
        .font(Font.title.italic())
    }
    
}
```

### Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Your first solution was very helpful and gave me the right direction for my use-case.

Answer (score 1):

You can manually get the view's `body`. Although this isn't recommended, it *is* possible. However a better solution may be to pass in a closure to modify your text, see 2nd solution. Both answers achieve the same thing.

#### Solution #1 (not recommended)

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        CustomText("Custom text")
            .getText()
            .bold()
            .environment(\.font, .largeTitle)
    }
}


struct CustomText: View {
    private let content: String

    init(_ content: String) {
        self.content = content
    }

    var body: some View {
        // Apply whatever modifiers from environment, etc.
        Text(content)
    }

    func getText() -> Text {
        body as! Text
    }
}
```

Here, the custom text is made bold.

#### Solution #2 (recommended)

This example you just pass in a closure of how to modify the already modified custom text. This is what I would recommend, plus it looks a lot cleaner.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        CustomText("Custom text") { text in
            text
                .bold()
                .environment(\.font, .largeTitle)
        }
    }
}


struct CustomText<Content: View>: View {
    private let content: String
    private let transform: (Text) -> Content

    init(_ content: String, transform: @escaping (Text) -> Content) {
        self.content = content
        self.transform = transform
    }

    var body: some View {
        // Apply whatever modifiers from environment, etc.
        let current = Text(content)
            /* ... */

        return transform(current)
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @George! Thank you for your answer! The first solution doesn't seem to work for me since the environment doesn't seem to be available inside `getText()`. The second solution seems better. I just have to make it work when passing in an actual `String` as parameter, but I think I can handle that. I'll try it out and get back!

Comment: @Martin I've updated my example so you can pass in a string. Also, the environment should still be available to use from `CustomText`.